# Why are many of my apps now called "<name>.app"

Tags: big-sur

Since I migrated to a new iMac Retina recently, I noticed most applications, including system apps, are no longer called <AppName> but <AppName>.app in several places, such as Finder > Open With:

[image]

It doesn't look right to me and I can't imagine this is how Big Sur would normally behave. Could it be a peculiarity of my migration from Catalina, or is it a setting, or linked to a setting I have changed with this unintended side-effect?

Comment: Did you turn on Display File Extensions?  That setting is interface-wide.

Comment: **Finder** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced** > **[] Show all filename extensions**

Comment: @MarcWilson not intentionally, unless its behavior is different between Catalina and Big Sur and it got migrated across

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks, I couldn't remember what the exact title was.  I have a Hazel rule that sets it on files in directories I want to see them in so that I don't have to look at them in the interface. :)

Comment: @MarcWilson this is indeed it, slightly irritating it is so system-wide. After all, when I choose "open with" they are _all_ applications :) But it is an easy answer though I'm unsure if it's a tweak in Big Sur

Comment: It makes more sense that it'd be interface-wide, vs chasing random checkboxes in different parts of the interface which would just be annoying.  Since you can set a per-file attribute to show the extension, I just have Hazel set the attribute on any file created in $HOME or subdirectories.

Comment: It makes sense it would apply in all Finder windows (including open/save file). I guess the "select application" window is using Finder behind the scenes but it's clearly not particularly useful to show me the file extension in this case. Might even be a simple bug rather than deliberate. But that's beside the point, if @MarcWilson wishes to supply a short answer I'll accept it (otherwise I'll add it)

Comment: I have complained to Apple about them changing preferences during updates.  But I have never seen them turn that one on.  They did turn it OFF on me once when I had intentionally turned it on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Finder** > **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **[] Show all filename extensions**

This is an interface-wide setting, any display of a filename will display the associated extension.

If desired, a per-file setting is available in that file's Get Info dialog from Finder.

Edit: Adding a screenshot showing what I have Hazel doing as I mentioned above.  This runs on both my Documents directory and my Google Drive directory.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not come across Hazel before, sounds useful.