# Hide specific file extension

Tags: terminal, mac, finder, file-extensions

I have just started using Sublime Text and their workspace files have the horrible long extension ".sublime-workspace", **so I want to hide that and only that extension**.

When I do "Cmd+I > Hide extension" the extension is still shown unless I untick "Show all filename extensions" from Finder Settings. But if I do that Finder also hides .png and such, which is not an option.

Is there a clever Terminal command for this?

Comment: I doubt that Apple have programmed such an option. It's certainly undocumented.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't such a command or option.

Comment: I do it the other way.  Let them be hidden by default, then have a set of rules in Hazel configured to set the option on files correctly in directories I care about, like ~/Documents and its subfolders.

Comment: @MarcWilson could you please elaborate on that in an answer - sounds like a good workaround :)

Comment: @TonaldDrump I already have, way back when. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425815/89967